# Panda3d Blender created room does not display properly

Tags: python, blender, panda3d

Edit: Not sure what I did but it worked still the walls don't display correctly....

---

Using Panda3d and python I have created a small room with a couple objects in blender and modified an example from Panda3d to do so and it worked for a bit but has had issues (walls not displaying etc).

This example worked slightly with two walls showing

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12781104/blender_glitch.zip

This example however doesn't work at all it is all black when I changed the colors of the walls and objects

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12781104/BlenderNotWorking.zip

Answer (score 1):

Panda3D will hide the back of a face as a performance optimisation, and this may be why you cannot see the walls. It determines which side is the front by using a surface normal. If you want your walls to be visible from both sides, in blender change the renderer to blender game, and in the materials panel, in game settings uncheck "Backface Culling". The YABEE egg exporter will export those faces as double-sided.